# How to uninstall an excessive version of python?

Tags: python, installation

I've installed python 2.7.11 from *.tar.xz obtained from python.org. I didn't notice I already had python 2.7.6 shipped with the system. Now I cannot run system settings (nor any of its components), Linux Mint:

```
 File "/usr/share/cinnamon/cinnamon-settings/cinnamon-settings.py", line   12, in <module>
import gi
ImportError: No module named gi
```

How to remove the 2.7.11 version? There is no "uninstall" target in the generated makefile. How to repair the native system python?

I've tried to apply knowledge from here but with no avail https://askubuntu.com/questions/80448/what-would-cause-the-gi-module-to-be-missing-from-python

The subject module is here :

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi
```

And not here:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ - no gi module


python --version
Python 2.7.6

which python
/usr/bin/python

ls /usr/bin | grep python
dh_python2    dh_python3    python    python2    python2.7   python2.7-config    
python2-config    python3    python3.4    python3.4m    python3m    python-config 
x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config    x86_64-linux-gnu-python-config

ls /usr/local/bin | grep python
python2 python2.7  python2.7.11 python2.7-config python2-config python-config
```

This is sys.path:

```
['/home/serj/work/proxy_mult',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Comment: Where did you get the `sys.path` from - 2.7.6 or 2.7.11?

Comment: Its 2.7.6, which is the regular "python"

Comment: Can you include `sys.path` from 2.7.11, just to see if it's picking up the `/usr/lib` locations?